# OutOfMemory : What is this Log file actually telling me?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

Encountered the following error :
"Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-8".

The following is the GC Heap History from the Log file generated. (Obviously not the complete log file.)
It does seem to indicate by the "edan space" that usage is 100%, but what I am not sure is if this information is telling me.

- Did the VM simply run out of space?
- Did the GC fail to clean it up or was there nothing to free and it
  really did run out of memory?
- Will simply using the command line parameters to increase memory
  resolve this?
- Was there a leak someplace?

  ```
  GC Heap History (10 events):
  Event: 632220.559 GC heap before
  {Heap before GC invocations=11023 (full 616):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116736K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  Event: 632220.864 GC heap after
  Heap after GC invocations=11023 (full 616):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116734K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 99% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1cffa10,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  }
  Event: 632220.866 GC heap before
  {Heap before GC invocations=11024 (full 617):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116736K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  Event: 632221.172 GC heap after
  Heap after GC invocations=11024 (full 617):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116735K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 99% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1cfff30,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  }
  Event: 632221.174 GC heap before
  {Heap before GC invocations=11025 (full 618):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116736K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  Event: 632221.483 GC heap after
  Heap after GC invocations=11025 (full 618):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116735K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 99% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1cfffc0,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  }
  Event: 632221.485 GC heap before
  {Heap before GC invocations=11026 (full 619):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116735K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 99% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1cffff8,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  Event: 632221.789 GC heap after
  Heap after GC invocations=11026 (full 619):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116735K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 99% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1cfffc0,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  }
  Event: 632221.790 GC heap before
  {Heap before GC invocations=11027 (full 620):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116736K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  Event: 632222.091 GC heap after
  Heap after GC invocations=11027 (full 620):
   PSYoungGen      total 232960K, used 116736K [0x00000000eab00000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
    eden space 116736K, 100% used [0x00000000eab00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000)
    from space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f8e80000,0x00000000f8e80000,0x0000000100000000)
    to   space 116224K, 0% used [0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f1d00000,0x00000000f8e80000)
   ParOldGen       total 699392K, used 699346K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eab00000, 0x00000000eab00000)
    object space 699392K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaf48d8,0x00000000eab00000)
   Metaspace       used 60711K, capacity 65403K, committed 81792K, reserved 1110016K
    class space    used 5955K, capacity 9471K, committed 21888K, reserved 1048576K
  }
  ```

Comment: If you can generate a heap dump file (there are VM arguments to do this), you will be able to analyze it with tools like Eclipse MAT .

Comment: I was hoping a heap dump was generated but could only find this file. I didn't think a heap can be generated from this file.

Answer (score 0):

> Heap after GC invocations=11026 (full 619):
>
> Heap after GC invocations=11027 (full 620):
>    ParOldGen
>    object space 699392K, 99% used

What can be deduced from that is that at the end of the log you're only seeing full GCs and that the old generation is full *after* the GC. So either your application has insufficient memory or a leak.